# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "operator<<"

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

I´m trying so overload an << operator to output a class named rational_t, which is a class that represents an rational number.

The function is like this:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const rational_t& r)
{ 
   os << r.get_num() << "/" << r.get_den() << "=" << r.value() << endl;
   return os;
}
```

It compiles good without using it. But when I try to use it in the main page it complains like that: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, rational_t const&)"

Any ideas? Thank you!

main:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#include "rational_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << a; // Problem here..

}
```

Class cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

#include "rational_t.hpp"

rational_t::rational_t(const int n, const int d)
{
    assert(d != 0);
    num_ = n, den_ = d;
}

// Other class methods here..

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, rational_t &r)
{
    os << r.get_num() << "/" << r.get_den() << "=" << r.value() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

class hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

#define EPSILON 1e-6

using namespace std;

class rational_t
{
  int num_, den_;

public:
  rational_t(const int = 0, const int = 1);
  ~rational_t() {}

// Other methods like get_num(), get_den(), set... HERE

rational_t operator+(const rational_t&);
rational_t operator-(const rational_t&);
rational_t operator*(const rational_t&);
rational_t operator/(const rational_t&);

void write(ostream &os = cout) const;
void read(istream &is = cin);

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const rational_t&);

};
```

Comment: In the .cpp you have ```ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, rational_t &r)``` wheras in your .hpp you have ```ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const rational_t&)```, that could lead to an error.

Comment: Do you mean the r parameter?

Comment: Fixed.. It was the const lol. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, one is declared const and the other isn't. Since the one in your header is declared const, your compiler is looking for that one, but the definition doesn't exist in your cpp file. That would be my guess.